# cannot add another object into an array containing different objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

Someone please help.

I am a noob here who has just created an array to contain all my polyclinics object. Now I need to add in a user object (patientDetail object) into this array. But no matter how i modify the viewDidLoad method, something just seems not quite right.. i cannot populate all the points.. only when i remove all codes that deal with the user object then it works.. Some1 please take a look at the method below and advise? I need to add in the patientDetail object and populate it with the rest of the polyclinics...

thanks for reading =(

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        _annotation2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CLLocation *userLoc = _mapView.userLocation.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;

    NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude);



   _annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       _listOfPolyClinics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

PatientDetails *patientDetails = [[PatientDatabase database] 
                                  patientDetails:_nric];

for (PolyClinics *polyclinics in [[PatientDatabase database] 
                                  polyClinics]){
    [_listOfPolyClinics addObject:polyclinics];
}

[_listOfPolyClinics addObject:patientDetails];



for (PolyClinics *polyclinics1 in _listOfPolyClinics){
    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

    if ([polyclinics1 isKindOfClass:[PatientDetails class]]){ 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate3;
        theCoordinate3.longitude = patientDetails.longitude;
        theCoordinate3.latitude = patientDetails.latitude;

        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate3;
        myAnnotation.title = _nric;
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString        stringWithFormat:@"%i",patientDetails.category];

    }    
    else{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.longitude = polyclinics1.longtitude;
    NSLog(@"Halo");
    theCoordinate.latitude = polyclinics1.latitude;
    NSLog(@"bye");


    //myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
    myAnnotation.title = polyclinics1.name;
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",polyclinics1.telephone];
    }
    [_mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [_annotation2 addObject:myAnnotation];

}
```

Comment: What is your console error, and can you show how you implement PatientDetails?

Comment: @Cyprian there is no console error.. it just doesnt get populated out... or rather when i insert this user into the map.. the whole map will show a world map., not the previous zoomed map where i can c all my polyclinics.. Do you know what might b the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have different classes in your array you can't use `for (PolyClinics *polyclinics1 in _listOfPolyClinics)`to iterate over the array. Use `id`instead, then ask the object of what class it is and then cast it to that class if you have to.

Try to change your second for loop to

```
for (id polyclinics1 in _listOfPolyClinics){
    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

    if ([polyclinics1 isKindOfClass:[PatientDetails class]]){ 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate3;
        theCoordinate3.longitude = patientDetails.longitude;
        theCoordinate3.latitude = patientDetails.latitude;

        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate3;
        myAnnotation.title = _nric;
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",patientDetails.category];
    } else {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        PolyClinics *polyclinic = (PolyClinics *)polyclinics1;
        theCoordinate.longitude = polyclinic.longtitude;
        NSLog(@"Halo");
        theCoordinate.latitude = polyclinic.latitude;
        NSLog(@"bye");

        //myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        myAnnotation.title = polyclinic.name;
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",polyclinic.telephone];
    }
    [_mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [_annotation2 addObject:myAnnotation];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.. I tried this but still could not populate that one point.. and now the map no longer zooms to the specific area i want but start off with a world map and i have to zoom to the points... Do you know what might still be the error? =(

Comment: OMG.. i am really a noob.. sorry your code worked wonders... total Life saver... Thanks Sascha... debugged and realised it was my sql statements that were giving me problems.. thx a million!